# Separar texto por espaço exceto dentro de aspas

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando utilizar um regex para separar os textos separados por espaço, exceto os que estão dentro de aspas, por exemplo:

```
Entrada: texto1 texto2 "texto3 texto4" texto5
Saida: Array("texto1", "texto2", "texto3 texto4", "texto5" );


Entrada: "texto0 texto1 texto2" texto3 "texto4"
Saida: Array("texto0 texto1 texto2", "texto3", "texto4" );


Entrada: "texto0 texto1" texto2
Saida: Array("texto0 texto1", "texto2");

Entrada: texto0 texto1 "texto2 texto3"
Saida: Array("texto0", "texto1", "texto2 texto3");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pode usar esta regex:

```
/".*?"|\w+/g
```

Explicação:

```
".*?" → seleciona o que estiver entre aspas duplas (inclusive as aspas)
|     → "ou"
\w+   → seleciona caractere alfanumérico (inclusive o underscore)
        e "soma" com os "próximos"
/g    → flag que seleciona todas as ocorrências
```

Como as aspas também são selecionadas, use `.map()` com `replace` para excluir as aspas duplas remanescentes:

```
entrada.match(/".*?"|\w+/g).map(function(e){ return e.replace(/"/g,''); });
```

**Exemplos:**

```js
entrada1 = 'texto1 texto2 "texto3 texto4" texto5';
entrada2 = '"texto0 texto1 texto2" texto3 "texto4"';
entrada3 = '"texto0 texto1" texto2';
entrada4 = 'texto0 texto1 "texto2 texto3"';

saida1 = entrada1.match(/".*?"|\w+/g).map(function(e){ return e.replace(/"/g,''); });
saida2 = entrada2.match(/".*?"|\w+/g).map(function(e){ return e.replace(/"/g,''); });
saida3 = entrada3.match(/".*?"|\w+/g).map(function(e){ return e.replace(/"/g,''); });
saida4 = entrada4.match(/".*?"|\w+/g).map(function(e){ return e.replace(/"/g,''); });

console.log(saida1);
console.log(saida2);
console.log(saida3);
console.log(saida4);
```

Comment: Não menosprezando as outras respostas, mas acho que toda resposta envolvendo regex deveria ser como esta, explicando de forma detalhada seu funcionamento, isso ajuda aos mais leigos(como eu mesmo) a entender o que está acontecendo, e não somente copiar e usar.

Comment: Toda vez eu me perco nesses parâmetros.

Comment: Para quem gosta de visualizar blocos e diagramas (Normalmente pessoas ligadas à programação sentem facilidade), um site recomendado para melhor visualização do Regex é o **Debuggex**. Em que [um exemplo  pode ser visto neste link.](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2cU0VttoNn7-Xk1_)

Comment: @danieltakeshi Não sei porque mas eu gosto mais desse aqui: https://regexr.com/3ls5g rs

Comment: Também gosto desse e do **Regex101**, mas acho que para quem está aprendendo, a utilização de ambos é muito válida. Eu utilizava ambos quando estava aprendendo. Pois as cores de formatação e explicação do **Regex101/RegExr** são complementadas com a visualização do diagrama de blocos do **Debuggex**

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso, utilizando look a head.

```
(?<=")[\w\s]+(?=")\b|\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ccy9h2/2

Exemplo do código js executado pelo link acima:

```
    const regex = /(?<=")[\w\s]+(?=")\b|\w+/g;
const str = `"texto0 texto1 texto2" texto3 "texto4"

texto1 texto2 "texto3 texto4" texto5

"texto0 texto1 texto2" texto3 "texto4"

"texto0 texto1" texto2

texto0 texto1 "texto2 texto3"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Melhor, use:

(?<=")[\w\s]+(?=")\b|\w+

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso também possa resolver o problema:

```
((\w+)|("[\w\s]+"))
```

Answer (score -1):

A REGEX que você está procurando é esta:

`[^\s"']+|"([^"])"|'([^'])'`